# How to flatten collection as Either.Right value in Kotlin Arrow library?

Tags: kotlin

I've implemented such sequence: ***Sequence<Either<A,List<B>>>*** and I want to map it to something like this: ***Sequence<Either<A,B>>*** (flatten in meaning of kotlin sequence not arrow's)

Sample code:

```
class Person(val favouriteColors = listOf("red","blue"))
    
val people: Sequence<Either<Error,Person>>
people.flatMap { it.favouriteColors } // I would like to have output of type Sequence<Either<Error,String>>
```

I use Arrow library (Either), however docs don't seem to be sufficient.

Does anybody have an idea how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your sample code, I guess you do not want a function that flattens `Sequence<Either<A,List<B>>` to `Sequence<Either<A,B>>`, but a function that takes a `Sequence<Either<A, B>>` and a function `(B) -> List<C>`, applies that function to each element of the sequence and flattens it in the way that you obtain a `Sequence<Either<A,B>>`, preserving the left side.

That can be done in the following way:

```
fun <A, B, C> Sequence<Either<A, B>>.flatMapRight(op: (B) -> List<C>): Sequence<Either<A, C>> =
    flatMap { e ->
        e.map(op).fold(
            { left -> sequenceOf(Either.left(left)) },
            { right -> right.asSequence().map { Either.right(it) } }
        )
    }
```

We first apply `op` to each element of the sequence and obtain a `Sequence<Either<A, List<C>>>`, then we either create a new sequence of a the preserved left, or a new sequence of all the rights, wrapped in a new `Either`. That all is flattened since we map using the `flatMap` of sequences.

So, if we have for instance a sequence

```
val seq: Sequence<Either<Throwable, Person>> = sequenceOf(
    Either.right(Person(listOf("red", "blue"))),
    Either.left(Error("Something went wrong")),
    Either.right(Person(listOf("green", "yellow"))),
)
```

we can call

```
seq.flatMapRight { it.favouriteColors }
```

and we obtain

```
[Right(b=red), Right(b=blue), Left(a=java.lang.Error: Something went wrong), Right(b=green), Right(b=yellow)]
```